# Oracle ADF with view Links

Tags: oracle-adf

I am trying to run my application with Oracle ADF using Business component
and when I click on the viewlink I got this error message:

```
(oracle.jbo.SQLStmtException) JBO-27122: SQL error during statement preparation. 
Statement:
SELECT Meldung.MELDUNG_ID,
Meldung.MELDUNG_MESSAGE,
Meldung.SACHBEARBEITER_ID,
Meldung.MELDUNG_DATUM FROM MELDUNG Meldung
WHERE Meldung.SACHBEARBEITER_ID = :Bind_SachbearbeiterId
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Binding Style of the VO (of this sql query which is erroring) to Oracle Positional and try (Double click on the VO and under SQL Statement section you should have Binding Style option).

If that doesn't work, try this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/ADFProgrammers/entry/bind_variable_and_sql_error